# in app engine how to specify column order of export (download) from datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

When I download my datastore (in localhost), the column order does not seem to match the order I defined them in the bulkloader.yaml, nor does it match the column order which i specified when i uploaded.

Should the order match the ordering in bulkloader.yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default, no, it follows python hash order, which isn't very helpful. see [csv_connector.py:252](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/csv_connector.py#252). we have a TODO to use the `property_map` order, but in the meantime, you can specify the order you want in `column_list` ([docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Configuration_File_Reference_Details)).